# Is there an official list of trusted Ubuntu system processes?

Tags: startup, system, services

List of default processes -- these running after fresh system install and after first system update. Both these most important and startup processes and these less.
Preferably maintained by Canonical and/or Ubuntu community itself.

Is there such thing?

Comment: Untrustworthy means what?  Virus?  Malware?  Security software that is ineffective at its job?  Also, every distrobution from ubuntu 12.04 to kubuntu to Kali Linux to zorin os to Ubuntu 13.04 all have different default processes and software packages.

Answer (score 1):

I really wouldn't place much confidence in the "trusted lists" your mentioning. I used to work with a company that used a website that listed "trusted processes" for windows through automatic generation. It was very imprecise and its sole purpose was to to get users to buy their products so they could "fix" the user's computer.

If canonical maintains such a list i am not aware of it - but i think its very hard and very impractical for such a list to exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you only use the Linux and canonical repositories, how can you get untrustworthy processes?  If you have untrustworthy repositories, you should deal with that, and any packages that came from said repository.  If not, then you're golden.  There are so many software packages in the repositories and its constantly changing, so I doubt any sane person would want to list them all.

Comment: Ok, I see. So it looks like I must google for every Ubuntu system process to know what it does. Oh well..

Comment: Yup.  I suggest learn about the filesystem first, and where things are placed and why.  Then you can get a quick understanding of what something might be, just by looking at it's file directory.  That should speed up your job.  A text book on Linux might help too.